# ios15,WKWebView,UITextField crash

Tags: ios15

iOS15 system:
1.click UITextField crash
2.Click the second layer WebView to crash
log:

---

- Incident Identifier: 4F61CB1C-53DB-4EFD-B38F-93B973BE5CCC
  CrashReporter Key: 6fa29e4a6b7c708a032c474dff75ab04a89a6a5e Hardware
  Model: iPhone12,5 Process: AppName [2986] Path:
  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/*******/AppName.app/AppName
  Identifier: com.***** Version: 8.0.0 (1) Code Type: ARM-64 (Native)
  Role: Foreground Parent Process: launchd [1] Coalition: com.*****
  [1262] Date/Time: 2022-01-28 16:14:58.8262 +0800 Launch Time:
  2022-01-28 16:14:41.9927 +0800 OS Version: iPhone OS 15.2.1 (19C63)
  Release Type: User Baseband Version: 3.01.02 Report Version: 104
  Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
  0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001812e01ec Exception Note:
  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
  Terminating Process: 888 handler [2986] Triggered by Thread: 0 Thread
  0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed: 0
  CoreFoundation 0x1812e01ec __NSI0 + 748 1 CoreFoundation 0x181333ad4
  -[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:] + 148 2 Foundation 0x182b4f0dc _NSGetValueWithMethod + 220 3 Foundation 0x182b0ab2c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 320 4 AccessibilityUtilities 0x196f8787c
  __57-[NSObject(UIAccessibilitySafeCategory) safeValueForKey:]_block_invoke + 40 5 AccessibilityUtilities
  0x196f87640 -[NSObject(UIAccessibilitySafeCategory)
  _accessibilityPerformSafeValueKeyBlock:withKey:onClass:] + 96 6 AccessibilityUtilities 0x196f879a4
  -[NSObject(UIAccessibilitySafeCategory) safeValueForKey:] + 240 7 UIKit 0x1f2042e38 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility
  _accessibilityLoadAccessibilityInformation] + 144 8 UIAccessibility 0x198c430e0 -[UIAccessibilityInformationLoader
  _loadAccessibilityInformationOnMainThread:] + 828 9 Foundation 0x182b15780 __NSFireTimer + 104 10 CoreFoundation 0x18136e318
  [CFRUN**** IS_CALLING_OUT_TO A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION] + 32 11
  CoreFoundation 0x1812f2cf0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1076 12
  CoreFoundation 0x1812ed4ec __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328 13
  CoreFoundation 0x1812cbd08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1944 14 CoreFoundation
  0x1812df468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 15 GraphicsServices
  0x19ce6a38c GSEventRunModal + 164 16 UIKitCore 0x183c81088
  -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 17 UIKitCore 0x1839ff958 UIApplicationMain + 2092 18 AppName 0x10060fed0 main + 352 19 dyld
  0x105151aa4 start + 520 .......

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

问题在avoidCrash中，
[AvoidCrash makeAllEffective];改成[AvoidCrash becomeEffective];不再全局捕获

发现崩溃在avoidCrashMethodSignatureForSelector:
这个方法里转发底层方法_navigationControllerContentInsetAdjustment时候崩溃

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).